Book recommendations
I'm going to Israel in the end of January and would like to buy books. I only have one suitcase, so I'd rather buy isolated books than full sets.
I'm learning hebrew by studying mishnayot Kehati with a dictionary, and so far I've finished sedarim moed, nashim, nezikin and just finished massechet Peah on zeraim, so my current hebrew is okay.
I'm currently studying Kehati's commentary, Chafetz Chaim's Shmirat Halashon, Tanya, Kanievsky's Orchot Yosher and Yessod VeShoresh Haavodah (but for that one I need Artscroll's english commentary since there's a lot of Aramaic and kabalah).

Welcome to Mi Yodeya to learn with us! Please visit the Help Center for tips on how to use the site. You question creates a possibility for a wide range of opinions. It is better if you ask it from people who know you, your abilities, and interests. Jewish people have been writing books for over 3500 years. The choice is exponentially big. Please edit your question to narrow the scope.

Welcome to MiYodeya Mario and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

We have lots of book recommendation questions but they are typically much more directed and narrow - otherwise they are impossible to answer. You seem to be looking for Hebrew sefarim, if that is the case please specify this. Also it would be helpful for you to consult with a Rav who knows you well and understand what might be most helpful to you at your current stage of learning

Missing on your list and which might be of interest: halacha (Mishna Brura?, Orchot Shabbat?, Mishne Torah, responsa), Mesilat Yesharim

Also please tell us what general region of the world you live in....there are things that are quite easily available in, say, New York or London (and therefore not worth picking up in Israel) that might be harder to find in Medellin, Colombia for example
